# Numeric text fields in iPhone settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, application-settings

I recently checked out this Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

And I can now add settings.bundle into my app and can use it.
I can edit Root.plist and I know how to use text fields in this but what I want the user to enter is numeric values.

The default text field allows user to enter any text but I want to take only numeric values from users.

How to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Simply set keyboard type to number pad. Refer the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself after surfing the net while and found the answer here:

http://devrichardagreene.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-user-configurations-on-iphone.html